# Resharper warning hides quick info

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, resharper

Often when starting a method, I haven't yet used a variable so Resharper quickly gives the warning:

> Local variable 'xxx' is never used

However, this frustratingly blocks the information on type declaration I might need from Visual Studio.

Even when I manually invoke the *Quick Info* tooltip with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
[image: Quick Info]

It still masks out the info:

[image: Hidden]

As a workaround, I've just begun immediately using the variable so the popup goes away:

[image: WorkAround]

But there has to be something better.  Is there some type of integration where I can see both?

Comment: I have this exact issue and was about to ask the same question. Sorry to see no answers. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, just the workaround I listed.